# Clear Contents on a limited range

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to clear the contents of columns B:O starting with Row 11 for every third row (using a macro specifically,) but can't seem to find anything that works. The closest I have gotten is

```
Sub Clear_Weekly()
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Range
x = 11
y = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Do
Cells(x, 2).ClearContents
Cells(x, 3).ClearContents
Cells(x, 4).ClearContents
Cells(x, 5).ClearContents
Cells(x, 6).ClearContents
Cells(x, 7).ClearContents
Cells(x, 8).ClearContents
Cells(x, 9).ClearContents
Cells(x, 10).ClearContents
Cells(x, 11).ClearContents
Cells(x, 12).ClearContents
Cells(x, 13).ClearContents
Cells(x, 14).ClearContents
Cells(x, 15).ClearContents
x = x + 3
Loop While x <= y
End Sub
```

I'm sure I don't need all the repeating ClearContents, as well, but I am still new to this

The current attempt is

```
Sub ClearWeekly()

   With ActiveSheet
       Dim lastRow As Long
       lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

       Dim i As Long
       For i = 11 to lastRow Step 3
           .Range("B" & i & ":O" & i).ClearContents
       Next
   End With

End Sub
```

But that seems to stop after deleting the first row.

Comment: Fully qualify your range references, e.g. via `ThisWorkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(... ` or the project's sheet Code(Name) `Sheet1.Cells(... ` to assure to get the correct sheet (if not indicated `Cells()` refer to the active sheet, which needn't be the one you want).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to opt for an easier solution and just duplicate the same code one over since it is very unlikely that Monday in a weekly attendance would be blank. Current code is

```
Sub ClearWeekly()

   With ActiveSheet
       Dim lastRow As Long
       lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

       Dim i As Long
       For i = 11 To lastRow Step 3
           .Range("B" & i & ":O" & i).ClearContents
       Next
   End With
   With ActiveSheet
       Dim lastRow2 As Long
       lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

       Dim j As Long
       For j = 11 To lastRow2 Step 3
           .Range("B" & j & ":O" & j).ClearContents
       Next
   End With

End Sub
```

And it seems to work so far. I will update this if it fails me.